# Applying php function on string inside variable

Tags: php

I am translating some text using gettext library and i need to translate part of string which is stored in variable. Display username needs to be wrapped like this:
`<?php echo _f("Display username") ?>`
Here is my current code

```
function _f($text){
global $locale_fetch;
return $locale_fetch->translate($text);
}
$solution='. 

<div id="askmove">

<input type="submit" value="Ask" id="pask">

<div id="nudi" style="color:gray;">Display username
<input type="checkbox" id="potpisanje">
</div>

<div id="premains">
300
</div>
</div>
';
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: You could query all  `//text()[contains('yourstring')]` nodes with `DOMXpath`.

Comment: the problem is how do i put Display username, which is inside solution variable to be wrapped with _f function

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that.

Comment: Please dont use XML functions on HTML code, you will go insane! I would add parsable brackets around your text and then use a nice reg_exp to get all those texts. ex: `%trans Display username%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

outside variable

```
$name = _f("display username");
echo $name; //Try this for test if the function works
$solution='. 

<div id="askmove">

<input type="submit" value="Ask" id="pask">

<div id="nudi" style="color:gray;">' . $name . '
<input type="checkbox" id="potpisanje">
</div>

<div id="premains">
300
</div>
</div>
';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds easy if I understand you correctly:

```
$solution='. 

<div id="askmove">

<input type="submit" value="Ask" id="pask">

<div id="nudi" style="color:gray;">' . _f('Display username') . '
<input type="checkbox" id="potpisanje">
</div>

<div id="premains">
300
</div>
</div>
';
```

Comment: it does work when you call it like this <?php echo _f("Display username") ?> ... the problem is how to call function inside variable